# Django manytomany accessing related column

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm trying to get my head around how Django understands m2m relationships, in SQL you would just add some joins through the intermediate table.

I have a Container which contains various Samples. A Sample can be spread over various Containers.

So in my container I add a alias samples m2m field (essentially a book mark to the other table).

What I can do is get a single Container and display the form information, I would like to add the Sample columns to the form, if I do this for the samples m2m field it returns a multifield, but how do I access the other related fields through the m2m sample_id >=< container_id ?

```
class Container(models.Model):
    container_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    samples = models.ManyToManyField(Sample, through='JoinSampleContainer', through_fields=('container_id', 'sample_id'), related_name='container')
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column='location_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    icon_desc = models.ForeignKey(Icon, db_column='icon_desc', null=True, blank=True, default='Box',on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    container_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    container_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my Sample table I add the containers alias to act as a bookmark to the other table

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    containers = models.ManyToManyField(Container, through='JoinSampleContainer', through_fields=('sample_id', 'container_id'), related_name='sample')
    sample_number = models.IntegerField()
    material_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True, choices = MATERIALS)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    recovery_method = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True, choices = RECOVERY_METHODS)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

In this case I am managing the through table:

```
class JoinSampleContainer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    container_id = models.ForeignKey(Container, db_column='container_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, db_column='sample_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```

So now I want to display the contents of a single container through a form. I have the url's setup to pass the container_id.

```
# views.py
def containercontents(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Container, pk=pk)
    # objects = Container.samples.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContainerContentsForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            #post.user = request.user
            #post.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('allcontainer')
            #, pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = ContainerContentsForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'container/containercontents.html', {'form': form})
```

The Form

```
# form.py
class ContainerContentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = (
        'location_id',
        'container_name',
        'container_type',
        'icon_desc',
        'samples',
        )
```

N.B. The samples seems to list everything regardless of the container.

Then the html

```
# html
<a href="{% url 'containercontents' pk=container.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">contents</a>
```

which passes to:

```
# html
<div class="">
  {{ form }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it will list all samples and those who are for this container will be "selected" because the form will use the ModelMultipleChoiceField. If I understand correctly you need to add more samples to the container, if that is the case you have to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets.

Answer (score 0):

Your models are defined wrongly: You should not define the `ManyToManyField` on both models, only on one of them. So remove the `containers` field on `Sample` and only keep it on `Container`. Set the `related_name` to "containers" (plural). That way the relationship `Container` -> `Sample` is `container.samples.all()` and the reverse one is `sample.containers.all()`.

Now the purpose of a form is to allow you to select which `Sample`s you want to associate to a `Container`. So by default the field will be represented by a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`. The already associated `Sample`s should be pre-selected when you initialise the form with a `Container` instance.

You can narrow the samples to select from by specifying the `queryset` for the field, by overriding the default field in the form:

```
class ContainerContentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # same code here

    samples = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Sample.objects.filter(...)
    )
```

You say you want to "display the contents of a `Container` through the form", if you just want to display, why use a form? To just display the contents, loop through the related samples and display them:

```
{% for sample in form.instance.samples.all %}
    {{ sample.sample_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: You should rename your ids to `id`. `sample.sample_id` is bad programming style. But I already told you that.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `Container.samples.all()` with the uppercase?  I tried this in shell, says object has no attribute 'all'. `Container.samples ` returns `<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyToManyDescriptor object at 0x0000020571E026D8>` I'll continue to study the code you posted.

Comment: no, I meant a `container` instance. You can't fetch concrete associated `Sample` instances on the class itself.